# How to avoid duplicates in a repeated SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm very new to mysql and php. I've been tasked to create several webpages which pull questions and answers from a mysql table and present them in a quiz like form. The questions are pulled at random from the table in the select query.

My issue seems to be that when sent to a new page, I see the same questions repeated. This is what I'm looking to avoid.

Do I need more queries? I'm putting on 5 questions and answers per page and use a submit button to continue onto the next page. Would it be possible to re-route to the same php page? I can provide more code upon request.

Here is the one query I am using to pull the questions and the answers from my table.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM a9_questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5" ;
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: Are the same exact series of questions being repeated? Or are there simply instances of a certain question appearing more often than not? One could be an actual issue (i.e. the ordering mechanism) while the other could be just too small of a sample size.

Comment: The sample size is only 24 so it is small. All of the questions and answers are unique within the table. Here is an example of one of the 24 questions.(They're all formatted the same way) 




INSERT INTO `a9_questions` (`id`, `question`, `answer_a`, `answer_b`, `IE`, `SN`, `FT`, `JP`) VALUES(1, 'At a social event I am more likely to interact with...', 'a few close friends', 'lots of friends or strangers', -1, 0, 0, 0);

Comment: `DISTRICT *` is a meaningless concept